# TouchableOpacity in absolute position view on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, touchableopacity

I'm building the react native project.
This code works well on Android but doesn't work well on ios.
if I touch the first half of the button, it works, but touch doesn't work on the end of the button.

```
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, alignSelf: 'center', width: 300}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{console.log('clicked!');}>

          <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', width: 300}}>
            <Text style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green', width: '100%', textAlign: 'center'}}>
            Click Me!
            </Text>
           </View>

        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```